# How to prevent an object from being written-over inside a boolean method?

Tags: java, object, methods, null, boolean

I'm trying to do the following:

Write a Boolean method that adds an account to the pattern.

a. It should have a parameter for rate and one for the account type.

b. This account becomes the patron’s first account if they don’t already have one, or their second if they already have a single account.

c. If they already have two accounts the method returns false, otherwise it returns
true.

**Here is the Code :**

```
public class Assignment6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(BankPatron.addAccount(11,AccountType.CD));
        System.out.println(BankPatron.addAccount(12,AccountType.CD));
        System.out.println(BankPatron.addAccount(13,AccountType.CD));
    }
}

class BankPatron {
    public static BankAccount account1;
    public static BankAccount account2;
    public static Boolean addAccount(double rate, AccountType type) {
        if (account1 == null) {
            BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount("","",rate,type);
            System.out.println(account1.getRate());
            return true;
        }
        else if (account2 == null) {
            BankAccount account2 = new BankAccount("","",rate,type);
            System.out.println(account2.getRate());
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
11.0
true
12.0
true
13.0
true
```

So that means the account1 object is being written-over three times, right?  How do I get account1 to become saved after addAccount finishes, so that once addAccount runs again it will see that account1 is no longer null?

Answer (score 3):

The local variable in your `if`-block is shadowing your static field.

Instead of:

```
if (account1 == null) {
    BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount("", "", rate, type);
    // ...
}
```

It should be:

```
if (account1 == null) {
    account1 = new BankAccount("", "", rate, type);
    // ...
}
```

Most likely, you will also want to refactor `BankPatron` to not use `static` fields/methods, but instance fields/methods instead.

This will allow you to write:

```
BankPatron bankPatron = new BankPatron();
bankPatron.addAccount(11, AccountType.CD);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid redeclaring account1 and account2 inside if condition.

```
if (account1 == null) {
            BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount("","",rate,type);
....
else if (account2 == null) {
        BankAccount account2 = new BankAccount("","",rate,type);
```

This should be:

```
if (account1 == null) {
                account1 = new BankAccount("","",rate,type);
.....
else if (account2 == null) {
        account2 = new BankAccount("","",rate,type);
```

And if your program is multithreaded  then make this method synchronized by doing:

```
public synchronized static Boolean addAccount(double rate, AccountType type) {
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking that the account1 is null, you are creating the new BankAccount object and assigning it to local variable account1 and NOT the 'account1' field.
Look at this line in your code

```
 BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount("","",rate,type);
```

The scope of this account1 variable will be within the if block. So your assignment will happen to the local 'account1' object instead of static field 'account1'

Just replace this line of code with following:

```
account1 = new BankAccount("","",rate,type);
```

Also make similar changes for account2 in the else if block.
You will get the desired result

```
11.0
true
12.0
true
false
```